# How to use FFMPEG with php lunarpages cPanel

Tags: php

I'm trying to get ffmpeg to work on my Web server,  hosted by lunarpages' a cPanel. on their website they said that ffmpeg should be installed, and I just have to add extension=ffmpeg.so. In my php.ini file, which I did. However, running 
    echo exec ("ffmpeg -version");
doesn't display anything when loaded from the my Web browser. am I missing something? is there some extra step to take to get ffmpeg to work here?

Comment: cpanel is a management interface for a server. it doesn't "host" anything.

Comment: so then my host is lunarpages. The real question is how to install ffmpeg if it's not installed, and if it is how to check if it's installed and use it